# Preserve url parameters if user is not authenticated on specific page (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm passing these params from `firstsite.com`

`param1 = value`

`param2 = value`

to

`secondsite.com`

Like this

http://secondsite.com/pay?param1=value&param2=value

But the `pay.blade.php` is under of `middleware`

where `pay.blade.php` accessible only for authenticated users.

and I want to redirect them to http://secondsite.com/login?param1=value&param2=value

where params is still exists.

But in my case the params of course disappears and redirect to `login.blade.php` since it is stated on my `web.php` routes.

Here's my route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> ['auth']], function(){
Route::get('/pay', 'PayController@index');
});
```

**PayController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    if(session()->get('merchId') == "")
    {
        abort(404);
    }
    else
    {
        return view('pay');
    }
}
```

But as of now I'm declaring `abort(404)` and will revise it once I'm done with my objective

Is it possible to keep those params going to `login.blade.php`?

Comment: Laravel should do this by default if you're using the default auth middleware and exception handler.

Comment: When I access on http://secondsite.com/pay?param1=value&param2=value where I'm not authenticated user it redirects to http://secondsite.com/login which is good. But the param1 and 2 are missing. Is there anything I need to do with my route?

Comment: After you finish logging in you should be redirected back to `http://secondsite.com/pay?param1=value&param2=value` if everything goes well. Is it not working?